# Capturing all HTML in a form including text field values without posts

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm working a form builder interface for users to add various input fields, and text areas that they add to categories and sub categories.

I've worked out the Javascript (JQuery) to generate the nested categories and input fields for the user to fill out.

I need to capture this exact generated HTML including the values in the input fields so that when they go back in to edit this form, it's as they last left off.

I had tried using $("#myForm").html() and saving it to a hidden text area which is saved to the database. This is fine except the .html() does NOT capture what has been entered in the input fields.

Later on, I need to parse out this generated HTML, filter out all the add/remove buttons and end up with the nested categories and form field values.

My thought was to bind keyup events on all the fields to update their own value field and then the .html() could capture it then? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going through the trouble of parsing your generated html to regenerate your form, it would probably be easier to use jQuery's built-in form serialization function to store form values:

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I initially hadn't considered that approach because I needed all the form fields as well as the HTML wrapping them. 

I suppose I could grab the serialized stuff, grab the HTML and then work them back into each-other later

Also, btw - adding the keyup handler to update its value attribute didn't seem to work anyway.
var sender = $(e.currentTarget);
sender.attr("value", sender.val());

Comment: You could use `html` *and* `serialize`, thus saving you the hassle of the approach you mentioned (binding keyup events to all the form fields...).

Comment: Though i didn't end up doing exactly like this, it's a hybrid and this put me in the right direction. There are other things in this form besides this "form builder" a regular jquery.serialize() wouldn't cut it. I needed to serialize fields within a specific block of html, easy enough. I store this serialization and the generated html. When a user comes into to edit the "form builder's" fields, i generate the html based on what was stored, then i read the stored serialization, split it on the "&", loop over it, then split it on the "=". Grab the field name, .val() with the second position.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this you're looking for.
I had similar problem, and after some research, I found this can solve my problem (not too efficient, but it's enough):

```
        $('#form input:text').each(
            function(){
                $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
            });

        $('#form input:radio').each(
            function(){
                if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
                }
                else{
                    $(this).removeAttr('checked');
                }
            });
        // I only give sample for input text and input radio
        var html = $("#form ").html();
        console.log (html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not store these into the contents of an array and store it in the DB and then store the pointer to this in a Cookie, Session or return it when the user logs on?

You could populate the HTML generated using the method you mentioned above, but you would have to iterate the fields and write the data values entered at that instant to the array you are going to write back to the DB.

Comment: Cookie wouldn't work in this situation. This is a component for a CMS that can be accessed by anyone via any machine. Grabbing, these as an array is not a bad idea either. I may use this as an alternative to Jquery.serialization() being that the inputs would need to have just sequentially name attributes (field1, field2, field3 etc) since they're getting a simple interface to inject new inputs into their form builder.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to store the HTML of a form in database?
What if the form changes(new fields get added/removed as a part of a release)?
Instead store the field values using jQuery.serialize and then populate the fields on form based on the stored json string.

Comment: Basically, I'm creating a form builder. The front-end user will see: Label Text: <input type="text"> Units...The back end user needs to input what is displayed for the Label and Units. And can add infinite number of items. I hope i'm being clear enough!

Comment: See my comment above what I ended up doing. Storing the JSON wouldn't have quite done it it because I won't ever know the names of all the fields so I don't know what the property would be called in JSON to find it's value. Serializing it as a string, and splitting on "&" and then "=" to select the correct fields and values.